# Dynamic Query to Select Multiple Entries from a Relational Record Table

Tags: php, mysql, many-to-many

Let's say I have a table which stores the relation between products and their categories:

```
p_id | c_id
-----+-----
  1  |  1
  1  |  2
  2  |  1
  2  |  2
  2  |  3
  3  |  2
```

As you can see, a product might have multiple categories. How can I search for products that have categories 1 and 2 assigned? The closest I can think of is using JOIN:

```
SELECT a.p_id
 FROM rel_table a
 JOIN rel table b
   ON a.p_id=b.p_id AND b.c_id=2
WHERE a.c_id=1
```

While this achieves what I want, it is not practical because my query will be dynamic. If I have to select products with 3 categories, this requires a difficult change in the query.

Is there a cleaner and more clever way to achieve this? I imagine something that selects first set, then refines with another category for the amount of levels needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use IN or Between for such things. You can dynamically create the values you put in the `IN/BETWEEN`

```
SELECT a.p_id
FROM rel_table a
WHERE a.c_id IN (1,2,3)
group by a.p_id
having count(1) = 3
order by a.p_id asc
```

or

```
SELECT a.p_id
FROM rel_table a
WHERE a.c_id between 1 and 3
group by a.p_id
having count(1) = 3
order by a.p_id asc
```

Comment: Edited. Please have a look!

Comment: Okay. Happy to help. :)